# Dock a panel to the right of the winform DockStyle.Right, but also specify a height

Tags: c#, winforms, dock

I am trying to find a way to dock a panel to the right of the winform but to specify
a height of the panel like 100.
The form height is 1000.

But the default behaviour is that the dock to the right fills the entire height of the form (1000)

Is it possible in any way to specify a height as I only want a height of 100 to the right in the MIDDLE of the form?

I don't want a panel that covers the entire right of the form with a width of 100.

```
                panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
                panel1.Height = 100;
```

Comment: That is not how Docking works. Use an Anchor-Right instead!

Comment: I tried to put the panel with Anchor-Right but nothing happens to the panel. It is still in the middle of the form?

Comment: Now I could see when I did resized the form. The panel followed along. This is the first time I use the anchor acutally. Thank you TaW!